# java.io implementations for GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, stream

Are there any open source libraries which offer implementations of some or all of the java.io classes and interfaces? Specifically, I'm looking for implementations of:

- `InputStream`
- `DataInput`
- `DataOutput`
- `DataInputStream`
- `DataOutputStream`
- `ByteArrayInputStream`
- `ByteArrayOutputStream`

If I were writing an app from scratch I'd just avoid using them, but I'm in the process of porting an existing Java app over to GWT. Changing the existing code to avoid using these classes simply isn't practical.

Since none of the classes involve file I/O, I figure it ought to be quite straightforward to implement these particular classes for GWT. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a standalone library, but Google did implement a little bit of java.io for their [Quake 2 port](http://code.google.com/p/quake2-gwt-port/source/browse/src/com/google/gwt/corp/emul/java/io/).

Comment: Bit of digging shows that although the source files in java.io are under the Apache 2.0 license, the project itself is under the GNU GPL v2 license. Bloody GPL...

Comment: Un-marked this as the answer this in the hopes it might get a bit more attention. If nothing better comes up I'll re-mark it in a few days...

Comment: Did you ever find anything better?